# Как будет выглядеть итератор QMap<int, QMap<int, QImage>> SourceImageMap; такого QMap?

Tags: c++, qt, итераторы

Не получается пробежаться по значениям `QMap<int, QMap<int, QImage>> SourceImageMap;`

```
int deskCount =0;
...
     if (QueryDeckLayout->exec(QString("SELECT url,name FROM tank.deck_layout WHERE desk_id = %1").arg(QueryDesk->value(0).toString())))
     {
       int countImg=0;
       QMap<int, QImage> tempSourceImageMap;
       while (QueryDeckLayout->next())
       {
          QImage shemeImg;
          shemeImg.load(FI.absoluteFilePath());
          qDebug()<<deskCount<<countImg<<"shemeImg"<<shemeImg;
          tempSourceImageMap.insert(countImg,shemeImg);
          countImg++;
        }               
                          SourceImageMap.insert(deskCount,tempSourceImageMap);
      }
...
deskCount++;

QMap<int, QImage>::iterator it = SourceImageMap.take(index).begin();
for(;it != SourceImageMap.take(index).end(); ++it)
{
 qDebug()<<it.key()<< it.value();           
}
```

Comment: У вас ключ внешнего массива целого типа, а вы ищете итератор по ключу строчного типа.

Comment: какой-то абсолютно бессмысленный цикл `for`...